# Is benchmarking php code with php code a reliable way?

Tags: php, benchmarking

I recently started reading about PHP and after some simple tutorials I am already puzzled about echo vs print vs printf.

This post is not actually about those three functions; I want to focus on the benchmarking part.
Long story short I wrote a small piece of code to compare those functions.

I already found a lot of tools for stress tests and benchmarking (even if they test a complete script or webstack), but I decided to write the code myself for learning purposes.

I got this piece of code:

```php
function stress($funct) {
    $time_start = microtime(TRUE);
    for($i = 0; $i < 10000000; $i++) {
        $funct();
    }
    $time_end = microtime(TRUE) - $time_start;
    return $time_end;
}
```

... that should be used like:

```php
$time = stress(function () { command; });
```

Is there anything else I should bear in mind when I test the functions?
Is it actually a valid test or am I missing something?

Please, note that I am not asking for a plain code review, but I am also asking for theorical knowledge behind the various options I could have used for the benchmark.

For example (code below) I used a for cycle to test the same commands 10 times.

- Is it advisable to split it in ten different tries instead of a
  one-go with a cycle?
- How much time is consumed by function calls instead of actually the execution of code?
- Should I use more/less tries in `stress()`?
- Etc.

Thank you for your time and patience [:

**TL_DR**

For what it matters, I tried the following:

```php
for($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
    $time_echo[$i] = stress(function () { echo "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"; });
    $time_print[$i] = stress(function () { print "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"; });
    $time_printm[$i] = stress(function () { print("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"); });
    $time_printa[$i] = stress(function () { $var = print("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"); });
    $time_printf[$i] = stress(function () { printf("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"); });
    $time_printfa[$i] = stress(function () { $var = printf("The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog.\n"); });
}
```

I had the following results:

| Take n° | echo | print | print() | var=print | printf | var=printf |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Take 1 | 15.32816 | 15.490262 | 16.953588 | 16.923553 | 16.099332 | 16.123995 |
| Take 2 | 15.781828 | 15.314232 | 14.98926 | 15.507461 | 15.547732 | 16.23509 |
| Take 3 | 15.617842 | 16.15986 | 15.610513 | 15.291788 | 16.299324 | 15.845392 |
| Take 4 | 15.91942 | 15.631404 | 15.398714 | 15.983449 | 15.675317 | 16.030814 |
| Take 5 | 15.284572 | 15.625322 | 15.542422 | 15.549754 | 15.584674 | 15.788824 |
| Take 6 | 15.526655 | 15.534213 | 15.436655 | 15.929052 | 16.15838 | 15.76694 |
| Take 7 | 15.490618 | 15.699726 | 15.366411 | 15.618184 | 15.618245 | 16.261611 |
| Take 8 | 15.583135 | 15.878102 | 15.854456 | 15.624761 | 15.978759 | 15.74526 |
| Take 9 | 15.635635 | 15.985996 | 15.872117 | 15.805193 | 15.95373 | 15.466458 |
| Take 10 | 15.786585 | 15.616831 | 15.73981 | 15.778323 | 16.463655 | 15.817156 |
| **Average** | **15.595445** | **15.6935948** | **15.6763946** | **15.8011518** | **15.9379148** | **15.908154** |

I decided to open this question because all the averages are pretty similar and I wondered if my function is actually a reliable way to get things done or not.

Comment: I think you may have missed the point of a `printf()`. It is used if you want to format data into a output not just to pump something out to the output buffer

Comment: The main thing about any sort of performance testing is about them being on a level playing field.  So if you are running several functions, it doesn't matter so much if they are affected by how you run them as long as they are all running under the same conditions.

Comment: @RiggsFolly You are right, and I am aware of the formatting capabilities of `printf()`. Thank you for your clarification, I think it is important!
Anyway I also think that testing echo and printf is comparing apples with apples: `echo "Hello " . $foobar . "\n";` and `printf("Hello %s\n", $foobar);` produce the very same output and they are worth of comparison, no matters how many more formatting options `printf()` has.
I'd like to read your opinion about it, too [:
Btw, the aim of this question is not what I am comparing, but how I am doing it.